# Filter paginator.posts

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I run a vanilla Jekyll (4.1.1) system. It displays the posts on the index page paginated and within two columns with this code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    {%- for post in paginator.posts -%}
    {% assign mod3 = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
    {% if mod3 != 0 %}
    {% include card_post.html post=post %}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    {%- for post in paginator.posts -%}
    {% assign mod3 = forloop.index | modulo: 2 %}
    {% if mod3 == 0 %}
    {% include card_post.html post=post %}
    {%- endif -%}
    {%- endfor -%}
  </div>
</div>
```

Each post has this header:

```
  ---
  layout: blogpost
  title:  "foobar"
  publication_date: 2020-12-11
  categories:
    - car
    - whatever
  ---
```

On the index page I only want to display posts which do not include the `categories` with the value of `bike`. It seems to be such an easy thing to do but I can't find a negative filter which works with the pagination.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hidden: true` tells pagination not to use it. It is not perfect but solves this specific problem.

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/

> Pagination does not support tags or categories. Pagination pages
> through every post in the posts variable unless a post has hidden:
> true in its front matter. It does not currently allow paging over
> groups of posts linked by a common tag or category. It cannot include
> any collection of documents because it is restricted to posts.